# Javascript : Assigning one array to another array which is a property of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this array

```
var collectData = ["one", "two"];
```

and an object

```
var datasets = {
   labels : ["something", "something"]
}
```

In my program collectData is dynamically generated and assigned values when the app is launched, I want to assign those values to the labels array inside the object. I tried following ways

```
labels : [].concat(collectData)
labels : collectData.slice()
```

but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to replace `["something", "something"]` with `["one", "two"]`?

Comment: The labels array is initially empty

Comment: The question is whether you want to add to it or replace it?

Comment: I filled in the labels array just to show that it too is an array of strings, I want to replace it

Answer (score 1):

Just use call the concat on the array which you have initially. When you do `[].concat` you're just adding elements of `collectData` to a new array literal, so you end up with just `collectData`

```
var collectData = ["one", "two"];
var datasets = {
   labels : ["something", "something"].concat(collectData)
}
```

Also you can always do `datasets.labels.concat(collectData)` sometime later after declaring the object `datasets`

Answer (score 1):

To modify a property, you use an assignment:

```
datasets.labels = collectData;
```

If you want to make a copy of the `collectData` array instead of assigning it directly, use:

```
datasets.labels = collectData.slice();
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand what you're trying to do but I have two options for you:

1. Add the array to the array of labels:

```js
    var collectData = ["one", "two"];
    var datasets = {
       labels : []
    }
    
    datasets.labels.push(collectData);

    console.log(datasets.label);
```

Result:

```
{
    labels: [["one","two"]]
}
```

2. Adding the collectData values to the datasets.labels array (other option than the answer from Amit Joki)

```js
    var collectData = ["one", "two"];
    var datasets = {
        labels : []
    }
    for(i=0; i<collectData.length; i++){
        datasets.labels.push(collectData[i]);
    }
console.log(datasets.labels)
```

Result:

```
{
   datasets: ["one", "two"]
}
```

Comment: @nashmaniac I can't comment on your latest reply yet but please post that code (that callback code) and update the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this, collectData was initialised in the global scope and assigned values inside a callback function. Then, when I tried to assign values to the labels array which is inside an object datasets and datasets itself is not inside the callback function but outside of it. For some reason I am not aware of all the data from the collectData array vanished once the program left the callback function making it completely blank again. And that is the reason why labels was still coming out as an empty array. I think I failed to properly explain the question. I thank everybody for taking their time out and answering. If someone can explain me the callback function quirk of resetting the array it would be great.